# Enter username or password via voice?

Tags: voice-command, voice-recognition

Is there a way to enter a username or password by voice?

Google's Voice Search only interprets entire words or phrases but I couldn't find any way to dictate **letter-by-letter** to an input field.

Is this at all possible in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can spell out words with the voice input, but it puts spaces between each letter. I can't see there being a feature to support this as saying your password out loud would defeat the point of having a password.

Now if you follow the "pass-phrase" model, where your password is something like "i walk on the beach to relax", then it may work. but again, I don't think it would be a good idea to say your password out loud anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find any way to dictate letter-by-letter to an input field. Is this at all possible in Android?

Currently, not possible with Google. Some other programs support it, eg Dragon or CMU Sphinx. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096295/395857